# Can I add custom integrated app to bim360 programmable

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

I have an integrated app in bim360 and it works fine. However, the process of add integrated app to each revit user manually is rather tiresome. The workflow should be (as I see it). User login to bim360, I set up the integrated app in bim360 (if not already done) and use the same login to authorize my app.

Is there any api which I can use to connect bim360 to my integrated app?

In advance, cheers for the help :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to [provision API](https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/bim-360-activating-api-access-to-docs/) access to a given BIM 360 account. The account owner having a control over which apps have an access to the account is as designed.

> > the process of add integrated app to each revit user manually is rather tiresome

It should not be each Revit user. Once you provision under the Account Admin >> Settings >> Custom Integration tab, the users under the same account should be able to use the same app.

If you have an app, which you can make it available to wider users, one thing you can do will be to publish to in-product app store, which you can find Account Admin >> Apps
(or you can see the listing at BIM 360 app store: https://apps.autodesk.com/BIM360/en/Home/Index )

This may not a choice if you are writing a code for in-house development.

If you think this works for you, please take a look at this page about the requirement and process and contact app store team:

https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/app-store/bim-360